# Android : SQLite wont insert data (return -1)

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert user data in SQlite database, it works for the code below :

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String FIRST_NAME = "firstname";
private static final String LAST_NAME = "lastname";
private static final String EMAIL = "email";
private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String USER_NAME = "username";
private static final String GENDER = "gender";
private static final String PICTURE = "picture";
private static final String STATUS = "status";
private static final String CREATED_AT = "created_at";

public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
            + KEY_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," + FIRST_NAME + " TEXT," + LAST_NAME + " TEXT," + EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + PASSWORD + " TEXT,"+ USER_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE," + GENDER + " TEXT," + PICTURE + " TEXT," + STATUS + " TEXT,"
            + CREATED_AT + " TEXT"+ ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

    Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String id, String firstname, String lastname, String email, String password,
                    String username, String gender, String picture, String status, String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, id); // id
    values.put(FIRST_NAME, firstname); // firstname
    values.put(LAST_NAME, lastname); // lastname
    values.put(EMAIL, email); // email
    values.put(PASSWORD, password); // password
    values.put(USER_NAME, username); // username
    values.put(GENDER, gender); // gender
    values.put(PICTURE, picture); // created_at
    values.put(STATUS, status); // picture
    values.put(CREATED_AT, created_at); // status

    // Inserting Row
    long id_inserted = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection

    Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id + " | "+id_inserted);
}

/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        user.put("idUser", cursor.getString(0));
        user.put("firstname", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("lastname", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("password", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("username", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("gender", cursor.getString(6));
        user.put("picture", cursor.getString(7));
        user.put("status", cursor.getString(8));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(9));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

    return user;
}

/**
 * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void deleteUsers() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
    db.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all user info from sqlite");
}

}
```

but when I try to add new column (code below), the insertion wont work, it return -1, I don't know way, pls can you help me to find why it return -1 and why the data not inserted into my sqlite table

Comment: Try adding a `;` at the end of the create statement. Also check your android logs, it will show you what the error exactly is. Post that too.

Comment: As pointed out by @EricBachhuber try leaving a space. That is also an error.

Comment: Replace `insert()` with `insertOrThrow()`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE columns were properly created? It looks like you have a typo in the create statement.

```
 + TOKEN + "TEXT)"
```

should actually be

```
 + TOKEN + " TEXT)"
```

Let me know if that helps.